# Does an LDA classifier separate the classes at 0?

Tags: classification, multivariate-analysis, matlab, accuracy, discriminant-analysis

I am reading some code where the prediction of a test trial's class amounts to whether its value after being transformed by the LDA weights is above or below 0. This is confusing to me as I see no reference to classes being split or separated at 0 in the resources I've been using to understand LDAs.

For any matlabbers, here is the code I'm seeing:

```
acc =  squeeze(mean((Xhat>0)==permute(repmat(Y,1,nSamples),[2,1]),2));
```

Where `Xhat` is the output of the LDA decoder (i.e. X*W) and is a matrix of size `no. samples x no. trials` where the samples are just different timepoints at which the classification is performed.

`Y` is a vector of true class labels that are either 0 or 1.

I understand the logic of the code, but not the theory behind how that creates an accuracy measure - does it mean that after projecting the new trial into the space defined by LDA weights, one class has negative values and one class has positive values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis) is a simplification of QDA in which you compare two quantities given some data $\mathbf{x}$: the likelihood of $\mathbf{x}$ given it comes from class $1$ denoted $p(\mathbf{x}\mid c=1)$ is compared to the likelihood for another class (which we denote $0$) denoted $p(\mathbf{x}\mid c=0)$. LDA and QDA both ask the following question:

> Is the likelihood of $\mathbf{x}$ given $c=1$ much bigger than the likelihood given $c=0$ ?

Specifically, they ask whether $\dfrac{p(\mathbf{x}\mid c=1)}{p(\mathbf{x}\mid c=0)} > t$.

The equivalent inequality is this: do we have that $p(\mathbf{x}\mid c=1)$ is $t$ times bigger then $p(\mathbf{x}\mid c=0)$ ?

Often the question is asked in $\log$ space where you only have to perform substraction, and the inequality becomes
$$ \log p(\mathbf{x}\mid c=1) - \log p(\mathbf{x}\mid c=0) > \log t$$
So if you want to predict class $1$ whenever $p(\mathbf{x}\mid c=1) > p(\mathbf{x}\mid c=0)$, you should set $t$ to $1$. This means that $\log t = \log 1 = 0$.

The code you're reading is right to compare the $\log$ of the ratio to $0$ !

Comment: thanks! This helps alot, but I'm a little confused by the following. Does that mean that the elements stored in the matrix `Xhat` are all logs of the ratio of likelihoods? Each of those elements is calculated by multiplying trial vectors (`no. trials x no. features`) by the LDA weights. Does that calculation output the log ratio of likelihoods?

Comment: It should be in the $\log$ space yes, but the threshold value depends on what your transformation is, please check the wikipedia article I mentionned. If your weight $w$ is equal to $\Sigma^{-1}(\mu_1 - \mu_0)$ then the threshold shouldn't be zero.